# checking for undefined variable with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, undefined, underscore.js

I'm having a problem with Underscore.js templates and Internet Explorer. Here's part of the template which is causing trouble:

```
<p>
  <% if ( typeof description !== 'undefined' ) { %>
    <%- description %>
  <% } else { %>
    No description
  <% } %>
</p>
```

When the variable `description` is undefined (which means I'm not supplying it to the template at all, the variable does not exist), this works just fine in Safari, Firefox, Chrome.

Internet Explorer however, doesn't work correctly. Instead of showing `No description` IE8 and IE9 show `[object HTMLMetaElement]`, and IE7 shows `[object]`.

Checking the result of `typeof description` returns `undefined` in Safari, Firefox, Chrome, but apparently Internet Explorer returns `object` instead.

I already tried Underscore.js's `_.isUndefined(value)` function, but that one doesn't work when the variable does not exist.

<strike>Does anyone know a workaround for this problem? (note that I am unable to supply the variable with no value - it either exists, or it doesn't)</strike>

**Update** I found a workaround in one of the Underscore.js Github issues https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/237#issuecomment-1781951

Can someone explain why IE behaves differently, and why the workaround actually works?

**Update 2** @John-DavidDalton has provided another, better workaround in the comments below (linking directly to it doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the `with` statement.

You can see what's going on using the compiled template's `source` property:

```
​var t = _.template('<%= v %>');
console.log(t.source);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

gives you (tweaked for clarity):

```
function(obj) {
    var __t, __p = '';
    with(obj || {}) {
      __p += '' + ((__t = ( v )) == null ? '' : __t) + '';
    }
    return __p;
}
```

The [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) is the source of your problem:

> JavaScript looks up an unqualified name by searching a scope chain associated with the execution context of the script or function containing that unqualified name. The 'with' statement adds the given object to the head of this scope chain during the evaluation of its statement body. If an unqualified name used in the body matches a property in the scope chain, then the name is bound to the property and the object containing the property. Otherwise a 'ReferenceError' is thrown.

So given this:

```
with(obj) {
    console.log(pancakes)
}
```

JavaScript will first look for `obj.pancakes` and if there is no `pancakes` property in `obj`, it will look for `pancakes` in the global scope. Apparently IE has a `window.description` value which represents one of the page's `<meta>` tags. Using your own namespace inside the template (as in the work-around) sort of negates what `with` does and keeps you from getting to the global `window` properties.

Comment: You can avoid the default with-statement by passing a `variable` option:
`_.template('<%= obj.v %>', null, { 'variable': 'obj' });`

See http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: @John-DavidDalton: I think that's an even better solution than the one I found in the Github issue.

Comment: The `variable` trick might not have been available a year ago when that Github issue was being discussed. But yeah, `variable` is a useful trick.

Comment: @John-DavidDalton: You can write that up as an answer and René can change his mind about which one he wants to accept if you'd like, I promise I won't throw a hissy fit.

Comment: @muistooshort actually your answer explains perfectly what was wrong and why the workaround works, so no need to add another answer imo.

Answer (score 0):

If you `typeof something` and the something is `null`, `object` is returned. Try checking for null after checking for `'undefined'`.